# Getting certificate chain in Android webview

Tags: android, ssl, webview, sslpinning, sslerrorhandler

I want to get the whole chain of certificates when Android webview fails to trust a server certificate. My WebViewClient looks like this :

```
onReceivedSslError(final WebView webView, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
if (sslVerifier.verify(webView, error.getCertificate())) {
                        handler.proceed();
                    } else {
                        handler.cancel();
                        Toast.makeText(webView.getContext(), "Invalid server certificate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
}
```

Above `sslVerifier.verify()` method somehow verifies the whole chain with the pinned certificate in the app.
Basically I am trying to implement dynamic ssl pinning ( certificates cannot be pinned at build time of the app).

Yes, I can achieve dynamic ssl pinning by different ways, one of them may be :

- To use custom TrustManager to get SSLSession and verify the whole chain from that SSLSession. But that solution I don't like mainly because I have to halt the loading process of webview to fetch certificates from the dynamic url that user provides in the webview ( or somehow the webview gets the url dynamically ). So, my question is - is there a way to simply fetch the chain of certificates inside onReceivedSslError() when the trust fails ? Any help will be much appreciated.